# afm2tfm produce .vpl file without kerning information

Tags: fonts

I have two `.afm` font files. Both were made with FontForge and both have kerning tables. After I processed them with `afm2tfm xxx.afm -T t2a.enc -v xxx.vpl` the one `.vpl` file have kerning data but another doesn't.

There are pair of trouble files:

[gostai.afm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ejcSYGylontLc94WtbB4gruht96SicL5)
[gostai.vpl](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w5hO-Zpxvn7ah6wED5zG4Nx5xOmL11hb)

I figured out that the `afm2tfm` doesn't write kerning data to `.vpl` file for digits. And one of my `.afm` file contain kerning for only digits so derivative `.vpl` file doesn't contain any kerning data.

Does anybody know how it possible to transact kerning data from `.afm` to `.vpl` for digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `t2a.enc` file contains

```
% LIGKERN one {} * ; * {} one ; two {} * ; * {} two ;
% LIGKERN three {} * ; * {} three ; four {} * ; * {} four ;
% LIGKERN five {} * ; * {} five ; six {} * ; * {} six ;
% LIGKERN seven {} * ; * {} seven ; eight {} * ; * {} eight ;
% LIGKERN nine {} * ; * {} nine ;
```

and these instruction override the kerning pairs in your `.afm` file. Indeed, if I make a local copy of `t2a.enc` and remove the five lines above, running `afm2tfm` as you did, I get

```
(LIGTABLE
   (LABEL O 47) (comment quoteright)
   (LIG O 47 O 21)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 54) (comment comma)
   (LIG O 54 O 275)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C 0)
   (KRN C 0 R -69)
   (KRN C 1 R -61)
   (KRN C 2 R -66)
   (KRN C 3 R -78)
   (KRN C 4 R -50)
   (KRN C 5 R -49)
   (KRN C 6 R -38)
   (KRN C 7 R -122)
   (KRN C 8 R -49)
   (KRN C 9 R -63)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C 1)
   (KRN C 0 R -35)
   (KRN C 1 R -21)
   (KRN C 2 R -20)
   (KRN C 3 R -33)
   (KRN C 4 R -10)
   (KRN C 7 R -45)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C 2)
[...similar omitted lines...]
```

Comment: It's have worked for my case. Thanks.  And I also had to remove `zero {} * ; * {} zero ;` from first line with "spaces".